# How to restore the Navigation Bar height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

[image: Navigation Controller height double] I accidentally increase the size of UINavigation controller. But i am unable to found a way to change its height back to the normal height from size inspector or interface builder.

The size inspector is not allowing me to edit its height. Any idea to restore it to its original height in interface builder.

Comment: if you not quit from XCode why dont you try cmd+z else if you are using XCode4 then there is a option of Discard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what happens you mistakenly change the 'Top Bar' value from attributes inspector.

What you need to do set it 'Navigation Bar' instead this  'Navigation Bar With Prompt'.

see in the image[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just drag in a new one and reconnect any outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this navBar and assign new one